# Arduino - How do I copy char* into char**?

Tags: c, char, arduino

I'm using Arduino and I have this kind of code:

```
char *swap[100];
prog_char settings1[] PROGMEM = "option 1";
prog_char settings2[] PROGMEM = "option 2";
prog_char settings3[] PROGMEM = "option 3";

PROGMEM char* general[] = {sttings1, settings2, settings3};
```

In a function, I pass `general[]` array:

```
void fillArray(char *arr[]){
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        strcpy_P(swap,(char*)pgm_read_word(&(arr[i])));  <== Error
    }
}
```

I need to pull characters from `arr[]` and store these in the `swap[]` array.

Comment: This question cannot be answered in its current form. Please provide more (or any) context.

Comment: What is arr? What is pgm_read_word?

Comment: It means your question has been down voted twice because people think you've done a bad job posing your question. Edit it to explain more what you're doing, explain what unfamiliar functions (such as pgm_read_word) do, in general make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: what a hell!! pgm_read_word or pgm_read_byte are Arduino functions. http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM 
If i title it "Arduino and exc." means that this code is for arduino framework and means that readers and VOTERS should know what i'm talking about!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `ampersand`, `arr` is an array of `char *`

```
strcpy_P(swap,(char*)pgm_read_word(arr[i]));
```

Maybe even

```
strcpy_P(swap,pgm_read_word(arr[i]));
```

Comment: i tried your solution but it still don't work. Compiler tell me "invalid conversion from char to uint16_t"